# Adding modifiers for class properties Python

Tags: python, oop, properties, class-method

I have a python class that returns Network interface IO counters (total, average and immediate sent/received bytes).

Currently, my counters are class properties.
Example SSCCE:

```
class IOCounters:
    def __init__(self):
        self._sent_bytes = 65535  # arbitrary value for this example

    @property
    def sent(self):
        return self._sent_bytes
```

Once the class is created, I access the properties as usual with:

```
counter = IOCounters()
print(counter.sent)
```

I'd like to have class methods in order to convert bytes to whatever I need (mbytes, mbits, gbits, kbytes...).
Of course I could manually write properties for all counters, but there must be an easier way to achieve this. Basically I want to be able to write something like:

```
counter = IOCounters()
print(counter.sent.mbits)
print(counter.sent.bytes)
print(counter.sent.gbytes)
```

Where `bytes`, `mbits` and `gbytes` functions would work for any property containing bytes that exist in my full class (sent, recv, avg_sent, avg_recv, total_sent, total_recv).

Answer (score 0):

So far I came up with a subclass of int builtin, which would add the necessary methods.
Then, instead of writing `x = 5`, I'd need to write `x = BytesConverter(5)` and can later use things like `print(x.mbits)`

The class:

```
class BytesConverter(float):
    def __new__(cls, value, *args, **kwargs):
        if value < 0:
            raise ValueError("positive types must not be less than zero")
        return super(cls, cls).__new__(cls, value)

    @property
    def bytes(self):
        return self

    @property
    def bits(self):
        return self * 8

    @property
    def kbytes(self):
        return self / 1024

    @property
    def kbits(self):
        return self.kbytes * 8

    @property
    def mbytes(self):
        return self / (1024 ** 2)

    @property
    def mbits(self):
        return self.mbytes * 8

    @property
    def gbytes(self):
        return self / (1024 ** 3)

    @property
    def gbits(self):
        return self.gbytes * 8

    @property
    def tbytes(self):
        return self / (1024 ** 4)

    @property
    def tbits(self):
        return self * 8
```

Happy to get any improvements or easier methods of achieving what I want.